# Changing object parameter

Tags: java, swing, listener, mouselistener

I have this bit of code

```
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {

        // Shuffle images array
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cards));

        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {

            // Create new instance of card
            final Card card = new Card(cards[i].getCardID(), cards[i].getCardImage());

            ImageIcon icon = card.getDefIcon(); 
            card.setIcon(icon);
            this.add(card);


            card.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()  
            {
                card.clicked = true;
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)  
                {  


                }  
            });  

        }

    }
```

**but the line with "card.clicked = true" has the error
Syntax error on token "clicked", VariableDeclaratorld expected after this token**

The Card class look like this

```
public class Card extends JLabel {
int cardID;
public boolean clicked = false;
BufferedImage cardImage;
ImageIcon defIcon = new ImageIcon("E:/Java Projects/UUR - Semestralka/resources/card.png");


Card (int cardID, BufferedImage cardImage) {
    this.cardID = cardID;
    this.cardImage = cardImage;
}

public int getCardID() {
    return cardID;
}

public BufferedImage getCardImage() {
    return cardImage;
}

public ImageIcon getDefIcon() {
    return defIcon;
}
}
```

does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot have such "flying" statement

Comment: posted code tends to speculations, guessing, for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE/MCTRE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Also, please create a setClicked(boolean isClicked) method for changing the clicked attribute and do not access it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put

```
card.clicked = true;
```

inside the method as follows

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
{ 
    card.clicked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`card.clicked = true` must go into the method body (inside `void mouseReleased(...)`)

Answer (score 1):

You should move it to the `mouseReleased` method of your anonymous `MouseAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

```
card.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    //card.clicked = true; <-- cant be here
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {  
        card.clicked = true; //should go here
    }  
});
```